# Jira: Find parent summary

Tags: jira

For a given Jira item can you query to get the parent ticket summary?

I know you can get `Parent Key` but we're looking for the summary so we can list the parent summary in the results along with sorting on it.

We're on v6.3.15.

Comment: From what I can tell this is not supported.  There is a change request out there for it https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRA-16589 and there are some plugins that do it.  But it's not supported out of the box.  So maybe that's the answer but I was hoping someone would say it's now available or there's a workaround...

Comment: We're in the search form..

Answer (score 0):

With just JQL it is not posible to look for descriptions. You could install script runer plugin, and develop some scripr, it would be easy.